# Security Timestamp Error in Dynamics CRM for Kingswaysoft

Tags: ssis, dynamics-crm, kingswaysoft

I'm getting this error in Kingswaysoft

> System.Exception: An error occurred when updating the component's
>   output columns based on the most recent CRM metadata:
>   KingswaySoft.IntegrationToolkit.DynamicsCrm.CrmServiceException: CRM
>   service call returned an error: An error has occurred when retrieving
>   metadata for CRM entity 'xxxx': CRM service call
>   returned an error: The security timestamp is stale because its
>   creation time ('2017-08-24T17:19:05.744Z') is too far back in the
>   past. Current time is '2017-08-24T17:38:18.038Z', maximum timestamp
>   lifetime is '00:05:00' and allowed clock skew is '00:05:00'. (SSIS
>   Integration Toolkit for Microsoft Dynamics 365, v9.0.0.6522 - devenv,
>   v14.0.25420.1)KingswaySoft.IntegrationToolkit.DynamicsCrm.CrmServiceException
>
> : CRM service call returned an error: The security timestamp is stale
>   because its creation time ('2017-08-24T17:19:05.744Z') is too far back
>   in the past. Current time is '2017-08-24T17:38:18.038Z', maximum
>   timestamp lifetime is '00:05:00' and allowed clock skew is
>   '00:05:00'.System.ServiceModel.Security.MessageSecurityException
>
> : The security timestamp is stale because its creation time
>   ('2017-08-24T17:19:05.744Z') is too far back in the past. Current time
>   is '2017-08-24T17:38:18.038Z', maximum timestamp lifetime is
>   '00:05:00' and allowed clock skew is '00:05:00'. (SSIS Integration
>   Toolkit for Microsoft Dynamics 365, v9.0.0.6522 - devenv,
>   v14.0.25420.1)

These packages are setup correctly and if I restart Visual Studio a few times it fixes itself. This seems to be happening randomly though and definitely looks like a bug. Is there any way to fix this?

Answer (score 0):

I've not experienced this error, but it seems like a system time issue.  Have you ensured the system time on all computers/servers is automatically being synchronized with a central server?